# Create shell alias with value from current path

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I want to create a shell alias which would run

```
command ew --constantswitch --anotherconstantswitch <name>
```

Now the value `name` needs to be extracted from the current path. the current path looks like this

```
[username@path-to-shell-xxxxxxxx]/path/to/directory/with/name%
```

How can I create an alias such that when I run `aliasX` it will

1. Extract the `name` from current path (which is last value of the prompt)
2. Add this path to the command above and execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alias may not be competent for the job, but a function surely do. Try this code:

```
myfunc() {
  command ew --constantswitch --anotherconstantswitch "${PWD##*/}"
}
```

The trick is `${PWD##*/}`. You know the automatic variable `$PWD` is exactly what you get when you run `pwd`, as well as Bash's builtin string substitution `${var##pattern}` that removes `pattern` from the left of the variable with maximum match. So `${PWD##*/}` removes everything except the name after the last slash, which as you described is what you're looking for.

In practice, a function is more versatile than an alias. If you still need to add extra arguments to the command, append `"$@"` to the end of the command inside the function, so any argument that you pass to the function will be forwarded to the command.

Comment: thanks. how can i bind this function to a command? can i do something `alias xxy=myfunc()` ?

Comment: @EmAe Sure. Just do `alias xyz=myfunc`. You don't need the parentheses when calling the function, only defining it. You can also call the function directly like any other command: `myfunc`

Comment: @EmAe The function is already a command. Just run `myfunc`. (Or, obviously, rename it to `xxy` if that's the name you want)

Comment: @EmAe A function isn't something you use *with* an alias, it's something you use *instead of* an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not trying to do anything involving arguments, an alias is actually possible:

```
alias aliasX='echo "${PWD##*/}"'
```

This will print the current directory name when you use `aliasX`. Or, using your example:

```
alias aliasX='command ew --constantswitch --anotherconstantswitch "${PWD##*/}"'
```

Notice that the alias *must* be in single quotes or `$PWD` will expand when you define it instead of when you use it.

For anything slightly more complex, you should use a function instead of an alias, as shown in [iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454761/3266847).